# Program in JAVA to generate random alphanumeric string

Tags: java, performance, beginner, random

This code will generate a pseudorandom alphanumeric string of given length.
I would welcome suggestions on how to make it more random. Beyond that, have I made any convention violations, Exception cases, and the like?
Also, is there any way to make it faster?

```
public class Test
{
    public static String getRandomAlphaNum(int length)
    {
        String charstring = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        String randalphanum = "";
        double randroll;
        char randchar;
        for
        (double i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            randroll = Math.random();
            randchar = '@';
            for
            (int j = 1; j <= 36; j++)
            {
                if
                (randroll <= (1.0 / 36.0 * j))
                {
                    randchar = charstring.charAt(j - 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            randalphanum += randchar;
        }
        return randalphanum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use StringBuilder to concatenate strings. += Creates new string every time and it is expensive operation to do in a loop

Comment: Please do not use all caps... that would indicate that each letter stands for something (an acronym).  That is not the case with Java

Comment: using `double` as type  of the counter variable is dangerous because primitive *floating point* numbers cannot be  represented exactly (when they have fractions). Avoid primitive *floating point* types unless accuracy is less important the speed in your calculations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for
        (double i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

And related loops should have the "for" on the same line (as this is a common coding convention.)

```
(randroll <= (1.0 / 36.0 * j))
```

This doesn't have to be a double; instead, the random number can be generated as an integer (to select which element from the array.)

```
randchar = '@';
```

Unless the random string is not random, I would not initialize the variables with sample data. I'd just leave them blank and then adjust the loop to always run at least once (a do-while loop) so that it becomes initialized.

```
for
            (int j = 1; j <= 36; j++)
            {
                if
                (randroll <= (1.0 / 36.0 * j))
                {
                    randchar = charstring.charAt(j - 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

I would remove the inner if-statement and un-hardcode the values so it can work with strings with any size. Applying these suggestions, it can be simplified to:

```
import java.util.Random;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int strLen = 100;
    String randString = "";
    Random r = new Random();
    String[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".split("");
    while (randString.length() < strLen)
        randString += chars[randBetween(r, 0, chars.length - 1)];

    System.out.println(randString);
  }

  /*
  Generates a random number from min to max inclusive
  */
  public static int randBetween(Random r, int min, int max) {
    return r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
  }
}
```

This approach is not optimal as the string is constantly being appended to, meaning that the string has to be re-copied every iteration.

Java introduced Streams, which allows reading forever from certain generators. Knowing this, we can read a stream of random numbers up until the string length that the user wants, and then get the character at the random string length:

```
import java.util.Random;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int strLen = 100;
    String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    StringBuilder randomOutput = new StringBuilder();
    new Random().ints(strLen, 0, chars.length())
                .forEach(c -> randomOutput.append(chars.charAt(c)));

    System.out.println(randomOutput);
  }
}
```

`StringBuilder` is used to append the random character as it doesn't have to be re-copied for every loop iteration.

Answer (score 6):

#### Separate random generator

I would either extract the *random number generator* into an **extra method**, or simply use `new Random().nextInt(36)` from package `java.util` to generate a random integer between 0 and 35 (both inclusive).

You could also make the method more generic by adding boundary parameters (min, max). So you can reuse within other limitations.

See: [Math.random() explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961788/math-random-explanation)

#### Variable names

Typical Java convention would name things using [Camel-case](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case). Also following Cleancode would put as much meaning into their names.

So variables (except simple loop counters) can be renamed:

- `characterOptions` or `possibleCharacters` or `alphaNumericChars`
- `randomCharacterChoice` or `randomCharIndex`
- `randomString` or `randomAlphaNumericSequence`

Answer (score 5):

here is my recommendation for your code.

1) Use int instead of a double in the loop; the integer takes less memory than the double.

```java
    //[...]
    char randchar;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        //[...]
    }
```

2) Use a StringBuilder to accumulate the result, instead of a string + concatenation (randalphanum).
The StringBuilder is always a better choice when building string in a loop.

```java
    //[...]
    String randalphanum = "";
```

3) Create one constant to hold the possible values, as a char array instead of using "charAt" on a string; the computation will be the same, but in my opinion, this will make the code shorter and more readable.

```java
    public static final char[] CHARSTRING = {
            'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 
            'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 
            'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' }; //(3)

    //[...]
    public static String getRandomAlphaNum(final int length) {
        final StringBuilder randalphanum = new StringBuilder(); //(2)
        double randroll;
        char randchar;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { //(1)
            randroll = Math.random();
            randchar = '@';
            for (int j = 1; j <= 36; j++) {
                if (randroll <= (1.0 / 36.0 * j)) {
                    randchar = CHARSTRING[j - 1]; //(3)
                    break;
                }
            }
            randalphanum.append(randchar);
        }
        return randalphanum.toString();
    }
```

**Potential refactor**

A) Instead of using the for loop with index and not using it, I suggest that you use a "while" loop, and decrement the index in the loop.

```java
while (length > 0) {
    length--;
}
```

B) Instead of calculating the position, you can generate a random int, in the range [0, 26]; using the `java.util.Random#nextInt(int)` method.

```java
RANDOM.nextInt(CHARSTRING.length); // between 0 and 25
```

Complete example:

````java
    public static final char[] CHARSTRING = {
            'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0',
            '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

    public static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getRandomAlphaNum(15));
    }

    public static String getRandomAlphaNum(int length) {

        final StringBuilder accString = new StringBuilder();

        while (length > 0) { //(A)
            final int selectedPosition = RANDOM.nextInt(CHARSTRING.length); //(B)
            accString.append(CHARSTRING[selectedPosition]);
            length--; //(A)
        }

        return accString.toString();
    }
```
````

Comment: Great first post, good job!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to your problem, I used a StringBuilder so I didn't have to create a new string and then, used an array of chars to make it super easy to get the value I wanted. The code would probably be slightly more readable if you created the character array by hand but I was lazy today

```
public static String getRandomALphaNum(int length) {
    char[] charArr = new char[36];
    String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length(); i++) {
        charArr[i] = alpha.charAt(i);
    }
    Random r = new Random();
    int randRoll;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        randRoll = r.nextInt(charArr.length);
        output.append(charArr[randRoll]);
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```